# How to convert a SURF list of features to Numpy array for KMeans clustering

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a bag-of-words workflow using Numpy and sklearn.

I want to limit use of openCV only to SURF detection and extraction. I'm aware there is a BOW class in openCV, but the documentation is lacking (for Python) and I'm looking to build the workflow so I truly understand the several steps.

So far, I am able to segregate my images into training and test sets and run SURF on training images, creating a list of features (`dscList`).

```
[trnImgs, testImgs, trnTargets, testTargets] =
    train_test_split(imgPaths, imgLabels, test_size=0.7,
                     train_size=0.3, stratify=imgLabels)

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()

dscList = []
for trnImg in trnImgs: # trnImg is a path to an image
    img        = cv2.imread(trnImg, 0)
    (kps, dsc) = surf.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    dscList.append((trnImg, dsc))
    print("# kps: {}, dsc: {}".format(len(kps), dsc.shape))
```

The output is as follows:

```
Classes = ['car', 'face', 'bike']
Images in each class = [10, 10, 10]
Min images per class = 10
Extracting features from 3 training images x 3 classes 
Total = 9 training images
# kps: 720, dsc: (720, 64)
# kps: 402, dsc: (402, 64)
# kps: 973, dsc: (973, 64)
# kps: 497, dsc: (497, 64)
# kps: 893, dsc: (893, 64)
# kps: 524, dsc: (524, 64)
# kps: 646, dsc: (646, 64)
# kps: 1185, dsc: (1185, 64)
# kps: 267, dsc: (267, 64)
```

I understand the next step is to create a Numpy array to then submit to sklearn's `KMeans`.

I wonder if you could help me with these steps:

**Numpy array:** I'm unsure if this is correctly building the np array `descriptors`

```
descriptors = dscList[0][1]
    for trnImg, descriptor in dscList[1:]:
    descriptors = np.vstack((descriptors, descriptor))
```

**sklearn KMeans:** Also unsure how to implement

```
k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, n_init=4)
k_means.fit(descriptors)
values = k_means.cluster_centers_.squeeze() # <=== is squeeze necessary?
labels = k_means.labels_
```